# How to add random colors for roles on creation? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

While creating my bot, I was wanting to add a randomized color on role creation type of thing.
This is my current code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from discord import Permissions
from colorama import Fore
import asyncio
#imports for reference


@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def role(ctx):
      guild = ctx.guild
      name = 'name'
      created = 0
      for _ in range(200 - len(guild.roles)):
       try:
        await guild.create_role(name=name)
        created += 1
       except:
            continue
      return created
#Solved, as with adding what FoxGames01 said, and removing the try it works.
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py comes with a function to [Generate a random color](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Colour.random).

Change line `await guild.create_role(name=name)` to `await guild.create_role(name=name, colour = discord.Color.random())` and that should work.

Comment: That didn't seem to work, it didn't make any roles, and I didn't get any errors.

Comment: Try the code without the Try statement, that's why no error appears. The code worked before changing the color role?

Comment: Glad to help you :D remember to accept my answer with the green mark to close the question and mark it as solved